# Google Sheets: Find last non empty cell in a row and extract cell value from different row

Tags: google-sheets

I have an attendance list chart, that looks like this:

[image]

The list is forever expanding to the right. I would like to be able to calculate days since last attendance, by subtracting the date of last occurrence of any string from today's date. Dates are stored in the first row, every row below is a certain person, emojis symbolize attendance.

I tried fiddling with =DATE360( ..., TODAY()) and various FILTER(), INDEX(), LOOKUP() functions but to no avail. WHat is the easiest way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way. Better ones exist, I am sure, and hope someone would provide them, but I came up with this:

```
=DAYS360(INDEX(P$4:$4;1;MAX(MATCH("✋";P7:7);MATCH("";P7:7)));TODAY())
```

It finds the relative column number of the last instance of characters specified within MAX() and then extracts the date using INDEX() function.